# String sql is not in correct format insertion fails using vb.net?How

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am new in vb.net i have sqlcommand string as shown

```
Dim query As [String] = "insert into tblDefProducts( Creation_Date, Product_code,line_item_id , item_name , category_id , subcategory_id , Gender ,LifeType, supplier_id , Acquire_type , Purchase_type , Manufacture_type , Pur_Con_Unit, Pur_Con_factor ,Tax_At_Retail_Price,  Sale_Tax ,Average_cost ,Product_group_id,status,Technical_details )

         values(  " & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() & ",'" & PCode_TXT.Text & "','" & LineItem_TXT.Text & "' , '" & PName_TXT.Text & "','" & CategoryM_CMB.Text & "','" & CategoryS_CMB.Text & "','" & ProductGender_TXT.Text & "', '" & ProductLifeT_CMD.Text & "','" & ProductSupplier_CMB.Text & "','" & PAquireType_CMB.Text & "', '" & PPurchaseType_CMB.Text & "','" & PManufacturing_CMB.Text & "','" & PConnUnit_CMB.Text & "' ," & Convert.ToInt32(PConFactory_TXT.Text) & "," & Convert.ToInt32(PSalesTaxPurchase_TXT.Text) & "," & Convert.ToInt32(PSalesTaxSales_TXT.Text) & "," & Convert.ToInt32(PPRICE_TXT.Text) & " , " & PTypeA & " , " & pActive & ",'" & PTechnicalDetail_TXT.Text & "')"
```

**2 Problems**

Input string is not in a correct format second  insertion of datetime value from datetimepicker1 to database column creation_date have datatype DateTime but datetimepicker gives value **#1/1/1900#**
also have to parse using sql

Comment: Use sql parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Braces around `String` is not necessary.

Comment: *As String* is not necessary

Comment: the values need a single quote like this values('a','b','c').  Your code doesn't have a single quote around each term.  The single quotes are in the wrong places.

Comment: usinng @ error must declare scalar variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using string contaternation to pass parameters is not a good idea for a number of reasons: Its vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, more prone to errors and harder to read and maintain.

In you question the problem is likly due to missing '' around some of your values.

Imagine if you only wanted the user to be able to update certain fields in your table but the user typed something like "Hello', ReadOnlyField = 'World" into a text box which you then concaternate into your query. The ReadOnlyField world be updated. With parameters this would be prevented.

If you use parameters instead you don't need to wory about '' as parameters are typed variables and not strings.

You also don't need to convert everything to a string as most .NET primitves has SQL equivalents.

See here for examples and documentation on VB.Net SqlCommand.Parameters

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: And also no conversion of Date values to string is necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database columns, which is not of type `string`, `int` or any other primitive, you should not pass the value without using the ado.net parameter system (you should never!). Because if you use `01.01.2015` instead of `System.DateTime`, the database has to parse the date from string to datetime/timestamp, which is often cause issues, because the date is not in a structured form and converting fails. In general, never pass parameter with string concation. One additional reason is, that this allows very easy sql injection and is not as stable as using the ado.net parameter system.

Comment: This is depending on many this. Database culture/language, application culuture language, ...

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I see is

```
Dim query As [String] = "insert into tblDefProducts( Creation_Date, Product_code,line_item_id , item_name , category_id , subcategory_id , Gender ,LifeType, supplier_id , Acquire_type , Purchase_type , Manufacture_type , Pur_Con_Unit, Pur_Con_factor ,Tax_At_Retail_Price,  Sale_Tax ,Average_cost ,Product_group_id,status,Technical_details )

         values(  '" & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "','" & PCode_TXT.Text & "','" & LineItem_TXT.Text & "' , '" & PName_TXT.Text & "','" & CategoryM_CMB.Text & "','" & CategoryS_CMB.Text & "','" & ProductGender_TXT.Text & "', '" & ProductLifeT_CMD.Text & "','" & ProductSupplier_CMB.Text & "','" & PAquireType_CMB.Text & "', '" & PPurchaseType_CMB.Text & "','" & PManufacturing_CMB.Text & "','" & PConnUnit_CMB.Text & "' ," & Convert.ToInt32(PConFactory_TXT.Text) & "," & Convert.ToInt32(PSalesTaxPurchase_TXT.Text) & "," & Convert.ToInt32(PSalesTaxSales_TXT.Text) & "," & Convert.ToInt32(PPRICE_TXT.Text) & " , " & PTypeA & " , " & pActive & ",'" & PTechnicalDetail_TXT.Text & "')"
```