# Datetime issues with vb.net and MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I am been creating a desktop form in vb.net in which I used datetime-picker tool. I want a format of **dd/MM/yyyy** so I kept that format from the datetimepicker properties.

But when I am trying to insert the records from vb.net to MSSQL, it will obvious shows me SQL Exception:

> conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

because MSSQL supports some ISO FORMAT and all.(MM/dd/yyyy, accepted and ran properly,I tried this).

So I thought to convert the date into vb.net, store it in a variable declared as 'date' or 'datetime' (tried both), into accepted format and inserted the variable into the Sql Command.

The following command I used to convert date.

```
1) Fdt = Date.ParseExact(From_Dt.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)-------- Searched the internet and got this stuff.

2) Fdt = Convert.ToDateTime(From_Dt.Text)

3) #" & format(DateTimePicker1.Value.Date) & "# ----directly inside the sqlcommand in vb.net.
```

and many other functions I am not posting now.

I am not getting one thing, all above worked and gave me result in MM/dd/yyyy (checked by adding watch on it during runtime) but it still gives me same exception but if I change the date format from datetimepicker properties to MM/dd/yyyy then the sqlquery is accepted without exception..

Even I tried datatype of the field to date/datetime/datetime2(7) one by one.

And even tried to convert directly into SQLQuery by some **Convert/Cast** function but the same exception I got.

But none of them worked, I had referred many links and this question may be similar to other but I didn't found any solution so I at last had to create this question.

The Code in which query is fired :

```vb
Try
        'Dim Fdt As DateTime, Tdt As DateTime
        'Fdt = Date.ParseExact(From_Dt.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        'Tdt = Date.ParseExact(To_Dt.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        'Fdt = Convert.ToDateTime(From_Dt.Text)
        'Tdt = Convert.ToDateTime(To_Dt.Text)
        If txtCompName.Text <> nothing And cmbCompType.Text <> nothing Then
            If CheckEof("select * from Company where Comp_Year = '" & Year1 & "' and Comp_Code = '" & txtCompCode.Text & "'", con) Then
                cmd = New SqlCommand(("insert into Company (Comp_Year, Comp_Code, Comp_Name, Comp_Prop, Comp_Add1, Comp_Add2, Comp_City, Comp_Phone, Comp_FAX, Comp_GST, Comp_CST, Comp_PNR, Comp_TDSNo, Comp_DrugLIC1, Comp_DrugLIC2, Comp_Mess1, Comp_Mess2, Comp_FDT, Comp_TDT, Comp_Distribution, Comp_Juridiction, Comp_Type) values('" &
                Year1 & "','" & txtCompCode.Text & "','" & txtCompName.Text & "','" & txtCompShtName.Text & "','" &
                txtCompAdd1.Text & "','" & txtCompAdd2.Text & "','" & txtCompCity.Text & "','" & txtCompPhno.Text & "','" &
                txtCompMobile.Text & "','" & txtCompGST.Text & "','" & txtCompCST.Text & "','" & txtCompPAN.Text & "','" &
                txtCompTDS.Text & "','" & txtCompDrg1.Text & "','" & txtCompDrg2.Text & "','" & txtCompMsg1.Text & "','" &
                txtCompMsg2.Text & "','" & From_Dt.Value & "','" & To_Dt.Value & "','" & txtCompDist.Text & "','" &
                txtCompJuri.Text & "','" & cmbCompType.Text & "')"), con)
            End If
            ExecuteQuery()
            MsgBox("Company Created SuccessFully,", MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            CompCreation_Reset()
        Else
            MsgBox("Mandatory fields cannot be Blank", MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            txtCompName.Focus()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: dd/MM/yyyy I want so by datetimepicker.text I get that format, later I converted to MM/dd/yyyy by the functions I wrote above but not working for me

Comment: One of the unambiguous ISO standard date fromats is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. Additionally you should not be passing dates as strings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358886/string-sql-is-not-in-correct-format-insertion-fails-using-vb-nethow?rq=1

Comment: okie I try yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm and say you @Alex, I guess I did it before but try and say you again....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Winforms [`DateTimePicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) has a `datetime` type property called [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx)

.Net [`Datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) [maps directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx) to sql server [`datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), and since [datetime stores no display format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028), you don't need to worry about the presentation layer's format at all.

simply pass the value property as a **parameter** to your sql statement. Further reading: [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)

Comment: Got this now "the conversion of varchar datatype to a datetime data type resulted in an out of range value" Please explain me what is this??? and any solution on this. @Zohar Peled..

Comment: You are sending a varchar value to your sql statement instead of a parameter with datetime datatype. Please edit your question to show the sql statement and vb.net code that executes it.

Comment: Check the code @Zohar Peled, I tried From_dt.value as you said but gave me different thing "the conversion of varchar datatype to a datetime data type resulted in an out of range value" ... lines below Try in the code are commented as I tried those things tooo...!

Comment: @bonny - Zohar's telling you to [use parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx). I.e. don't try to construct your SQL as one big *string*. It's the conversion to *strings* that is giving you formatting issues.

Comment: okieee, so I use paramater for the date instead of string in sqlcommand, is it like that @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Okie wait, I think I got it.... @Damien_The_Unbeliever
Just Tell you in a short time...

Comment: @bonny - your Code should look something like `cmd = New SqlCommand(("insert into Company (...columns...) values(@Comp_Year, @Comp_Code,....)");` and then additional lines as you add each parameter to the command - `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Comp_Year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Year1`, etc.

Comment: Okie so I learnt two things from you, 1) How to pass sql parameters and 2) a new way to write sqlquery in a proper order...
Thanx alot, Its done @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Also big thanx to @ZoharPeled

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever!

Comment: @bonny Glad to help :-)